# Mercurial: Better command line diff?

Tags: mercurial, diff

I am wondering how to improve the diff command as part of hg. For example, lets say I have this code:

```
line 1 
line 2
lin3 3
```

and I change it to become:

```
if($condition) {
   line 1
   line 2
   line 3
}
```

hg diff will show the original three lines with a "-" and the new five lines with a "+". Even when I run with -wbB to ignore whitespace and line changes. I understand what it is trying to tell me, but isn't there way it could be "smarter" and realize that I've only added two lines  (and increased level of three lines)?

EDIT:
Is it possible to have hg diff tell you what text was added and where? As opposed to how the "structure" of the code changed because of those additions?

EDIT 2:
I am running Debian (Linux dev 2.6.26) with Mercurial 1.0.1

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask what difficulty the current diff output is causing you? Also it would help to know what platform you are running Hg on as tools may differ.

Comment: `mdiff(1)` and `wdiff(1)` are in the `wdiff` package on Ubuntu, might be just the tool.

Comment: Lazarus, Faramir probably wants CLI tool that can be as smart as [xxdiff](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/doc/screenshots/xxdiff-snap-files2.html) in the face of minor changes.

Comment: @Lazarus @sarnold is right. I just want something "smart" enough to detect that all I added to the file was two lines, the if statement and the closing bracket. Instead, it shows me the entire block of code as removed, and then added again in separate pieces?

Comment: if it just presents you with the if and closing bracket you lose the context but it is very dependent on your use of the diff output. Each to their own.

Answer (score 5):

You're seeing those changes because whitespace changes count.  If you do `hg diff --ignore-space-change` you'll see something more like:

```
+ if($condition) {
   line 1
   line 2
   line 3
+ }
```

which sound like what you want.  You can also use the [ExtDiff Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) to call any of the alternate diff programs @sarnold suggests.

Also, consider updating Mercurial.  Your version is about three years old and current packages are built for Debian.

Comment: that doesn't work for me for some reason. I'm using the -wbB flags which include that, and even when I use the --ignore-space-change nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in something similar, but I ended up using DiffMerge (Windows only, but you can try Kdiff3 on Debian) as visual diff for reviewing changes like that:

[image]

Sadly, even if you generate the patch in the form you like (using other tools), in the repository history it will be shown in the standard mercurial format.